# How to open a big excel template with SXSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a 6MB excel template with vba and when trying to open it with XSSFWorkbook and it won't work, it takes 15 minutes to open the excel, which is too much for our needs.

I read about SXSSFWorkbook and how it's more efficient (memory wise).

Problem is, I can't open a template with SXSSFWorkbook, what I need to do is create a XSSFWorkbook and then pass it to SXSSFWorkbook, but that still revolves around using a XSSFWorkbook to load the file, which will simply take too long.

My code is like this right now:

```
File file = new File("Template.xlsm");
ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file); // Version that would take too long
SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); // Version that is more efficient but can't directly load a template
```

Comment: 15 minutes to open a large spreadsheet seems very very slow, should be much quicker with Apache POI normally, can you use a profiler to see where the time is going?

Comment: SXSSFWorkbook is for writing big files, not for opening them. You could try https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader or http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api